# Calling BLAS routines inside OpenCL kernels

Tags: image-processing, opencl, blas

Currently I am doing some image processing algorithms using OpenCL. Basically my algorithm requires to solve a linear system of equations for each pixel. Each system is independent of others, so going for a parallel implementation is natural.

I have looked at several BLAS packages such as ViennaCL and [AMD APPML](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-math-libraries/), but it seems all of them have the same use pattern (host calling BLAS subroutines to be executed on CL device).

What I need is a BLAS library that could be called inside an OpenCL kernel so that I can solve many linear systems in parallel.

I found this similar question on the AMD forums.

- [Calling APPML BLAS functions from the kernel](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/160359)

Thanks

Comment: Good question, if the BLAS library had a fast-path OpenCL access then it would be easy. But this is higly unlikely to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible. clBLAS routines make a series of kernel launches, some 'solve' routine kernel launches are really complicated. clBLAS routines take cl_mem and commandQueues as args. So if your buffer is already on device, clBLAS will directly act on that. It doesn't accept host buffer or manage host->device transfers

If you want to have a look at what kernel are generated and launched, uncomment this line https://github.com/clMathLibraries/clBLAS/blob/master/src/library/blas/generic/common.c#L461 and build clBLAS. It will dump all kernels being called

Comment: Thanks for the link @krishnaraj. Unfortunately my use case for the blas routines does not match with clBlas. For example, I want to solve 640x480 systems of linear equations (each system with 6 variables) so I want to build each linear system on GPU memory and solve it independently of others. Since I haven't found any library that does this job, I started to write my own blas routines acting on matrices allocated (their size is known before runtime) in private kernel memory.

Comment: Is your problem something similar to TRSM http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf2/STRSM.htm trinagular matrix-matrix solve

Comment: Not in its original form, but it could be transformed to a triangular system by means of a Cholesky decomposition, I think. Why?

Comment: Just asked if you could use blas functions in your case. Looks like your case is different